# Bootstrap and absolute positioned video tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have been having to mess around with web development lately and have been using bootstrap a lot.  One thing I have been trying to do is replicate how AirBNB has a video playing on their website and the content continues underneath it.  I've been trying to replicate this look in bootstrap, but I can't keep the look and feel of how their video plays, and have bootstrap play nice with it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero">
        <video loop="loop"preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/Croatia-P1-0.mp4"></source>
            <source type="video/webm" src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/Croatia-P1-0.webm"></source>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>This is a test</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 600px;
overflow: hidden ;
min-width: 1045px;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle that I have been playing around in:

http://jsfiddle.net/z2ps0q5n/

Any advice would be appreciated. From what I can tell it stems from the absolute position of the video on the page.  To my understanding, this is what provides the awesome look and feel that airbnb gets.

Comment: Take a look at this http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Answer (score 0):

with this bit of css I think it is good, but the mobile will be more difficult.

```
.hero {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```